# i3wm Blue square that wraps around applications

Tags: unity, i3-wm

So I need to change the bar wrapping around apps in Ubuntu (20.04) in i3 example here:

[image: Blue bar around apps]

its kinda hard to see but it indicates what app has the focus for typing or what ever...

Comment: You can check the official [documentation](https://i3wm.org). By "change" You mean change the color or disable it completely?

Comment: Yes the docs help me thanks for the suggestion